# How to do Figure captioning in Appendix of a documentation MS-Word

Tags: ms-word

I am doing an documentation with MS word and I caption figures with the chapter number like `Figure 2.1 - Diagram of bla bla`. But I'm failing to do so in appendix part because chapter headings are like `Appendix A - Bla Bla`etc. So It doesn't show `Figure B.1 - Diagram of bla bla` as I expected. 
I tried [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7UF4m8PjkM) on you tube but can't find his style "A Appendix" on @02:02 of the video. And tried also [this set of steps](http://www.k-state.edu/grad/etdr/word/wordmac08/appendix.html)  but replacing "6" for the place "1" in **field codes** doesn't help. Is there any other way to change **field codes**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by carefully following the steps on [this link](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html). It's really descriptive and helpfull.

I had to create a heading 6 (or 7,8,9 also can be used) style to make it appear on the quick styles on the ribbon by making it as my Appendix Heading format. 
[image: How it appear on ribbon after creating heading 6 as appendix heading]